# Bug in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

My EditText `inputType = numericDecimal`and I tested my application on numerous phones and it worked fine, but on low quality phone with Android 4.04 when I turn it into landscape, `EditText` fields are shown as password fields though you can type in only `numericDecimal` but when I turn back all fields are fine again. How can I fix this?

Comment: well, that is one useful comment. Thanks! But I have to make it compatible with all phones.

Comment: What do you mean by password field? Does it show the entered number with '***' ?

Comment: just input is shown as ***, when I close keyboard, everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some issue with this that are shown [Android Open Source Project - Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2626) and yet no updates in that,

Such as

**Even stranger behavior is that in *portrait orientation the input / keyboard* accepts the comma as valid character, but in landscape orientation the comma is removed from the input and the keyboard backspace button starts to behave strangely.**

Many more.